# Is there a way to change the active element by using a div id in a url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a div that contains a list of videos as a sort of playlist. When one of the links is clicked a larger version of the video plays beside the playlist.

I have attached the video title to the div id, and when I append #video-id to the end of the url I can see that the link is highlighted.

Not sure if it's possible to have it so that when the user goes to, for eg,

www.examplesite.com/videos#video-6

this video will be highlighted and activated so that it will play the video in the larger version.

If there is a better way to do this that would be great.

Comment: are you aware of url rewriting and routing in mvc ?

Comment: I'm new to MVC so I'm not, I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
var link = window.location.pathname;
var current = link.split('#');
current[current.length-1]; // <-- Current video
```

Comment: Why not use `window.location.hash`?

Comment: I didn't knew that was a thing actually!

Answer (score 0):

Grab the url and parse out the key word:

```
var path = window.location.href;
var index = path.lastIndexOf('#');
var dom = path.substring(index);
$(dom).animate({height: 400, width: 250});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you launch your video player from within JS script?
If you can, than you check whether you have an anchor in your URL or not, get the anchor from your URL, find your element by ID and add an active class to it and then launch the proper video.

```
if( window.location.hash ) {
    var anchor = window.location.hash;
    var $activeEl = $(anchor);
    $activeEl.addClass('.active');
    yourVideoPlayer.play(anchor.substring(1, anchor.length-1)); // Removing the hash symbol
}
```

Something like this will work.